# Php Register System

Tags: php, postback, membership

I  will develop a register system with php. First step user will fill basic information, next step payment information, next step more information. Theese step are different tabs top on the page. There should not any postback at transitions between theese tabs. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't have any prior experience with accepting payment information, I suggest using Paypal (or some other service) to manage the payment step for you. You can look through the PCI standards site, but using a third party service would probably be easier: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/

Answer (score 0):

you should do these tabs using simple CSS formatting.
There is nothing in your question related to postback, membership and php :)

Comment: When I clicked one of the these tabs should open new form.

Comment: @user811686 yes, sir! Exactly, sir!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a form for each tab, here are two ways how you could solve that:

1. You could create a UID for each user who registers, just use uniqid() and than you could send all the data of each form tab to the server via Ajax.
2. Or you could store via PHP everything in a Session and then after the last tab you could save the new user data.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the html part of the form (it stills exists in the page, only hidden), or you can save the data using javascript and at the end post it all.
you switch tabs without reloading the page in this case

or (if you want to reload the page in each tab) you save it to cookie or session or some temporary database record